# I want to create multiple context object in django views

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, django-views

```
def claim(request):
    entries = Child_Info.objects.all()
    ctx = { 'entries' : entries }
    return render_to_response('myapp/claim.html', ctx)
```

How to pass more than one context here?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for more objects in the same context?. If so, `ctx = {'entries': entries, 'another_obj': some_value}` should works.

Comment: Why do you more than one context?

Comment: i want to fetch data from multiple model or table and want only perticular field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want more than one context? `ctx` is a dictionary, you can have as many items as you like in it.

Comment: i want to fetch data from multiple model or table and want only perticular field